# Local DB throws Byte array truncation to a length of 8000 exception

Tags: database, windows-phone-7, linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to take a snapshot from a Map control as a WritableBitmap, convert it to a byte array and save it in the local DB. It works fine (I can convert the byte array back to the image) untill I submit the changes to the DB. At this point it throws an exception "Byte array truncation to a length of 8000". I didn't find any documentation about byte array limitation. Does anyone know how to increase the limit of 8000? My byte array is a member of my Model:

```
private byte[] _locationImage;
[Column]
public byte[] LocationImage
{
   get { return _locationImage; }
   set
   {
      if (_locationImage != value)
      {
         NotifyPropertyChanging("LocationImage");
         _locationImage = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("LocationImage");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What "database" are you using?

Comment: Is the field ever defined as a varbinary(8000) on the DB side?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you look at [the SQL Compact docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424.aspx), you'll see that a binary or varbinary field can be at most 8000 bytes, so that tells me that a `byte[]` column gets mapped to varbinary.  To get it to store data larger than that, you'd need to get the engine to use an `image` field type.  This might be as simple as updating the `Column` attribute like this (untested):

```
[Column(DbType="image")]
public byte[] LocationImage { ... }
```

Comment: VARBINARY(MAX) is not available in SQL Compact?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. It's exactly what I was looking for. I didn't think to look at the SQL CE docs. Thanks.