# Store a byte array longer than 8000 bytes in a WP7 SQL database

Tags: database, windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Local DB throws Byte array truncation to a length of 8000 exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431532/local-db-throws-byte-array-truncation-to-a-length-of-8000-exception)

The SQL database on the phone won't let me store a byte array bigger than 8000 bytes. I've looked at other datatypes here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424(SQL.110).aspx

but types that hold more data, like NTEXT, can't be used in WP7. I need to store a byte array of length greater than 300,000 bytes.

Any ideas how I can get around this issue?

Any help is appreciated!

Edit:
The whole idea is to store an image as a byte array on a local and on a remote server.

Comment: This isn't meant to be smart-alecky, but perhaps you should re-factor the design.  There are limits for reasons.  Phones aren't yet full-fledged PCs, and lack the power and memory of a true PC.

Comment: I understand, however I need to transmit this data to a server which will then store it in an SQL database. The whole idea is to store an image as a byte array on a local and on a remote server.

Comment: It's a duplicate, since the answer is precisely the same. So it should be closed.

Comment: Agreed - do I close it, or do I need a mod to do that?

Comment: @Cameron: just let it be.  The community will eventually close it now that it's been flagged.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Image datatype is supported.
See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286406(v=VS.92).aspx#BKMK_WorkingWithBLOBData

I would strongly consider storing data this large in Isolated Storage though, with a guid file name, then store the guid in the database.

Comment: It must be stored in a database as it must persist. Could you give me some more information about guid please? Seaching for it returns nothing useful.

Comment: @CameronFisher IsolatedStorage persists in the same way that a database does. A database is stored in isolated storage ;)

Comment: Oh, well ok then. Anything I've previously written in isolated storage has been wiped when i restarted the phone/exit the app. Eventually this needs to be stored on a remote database so I still require a solution please :)...

Comment: Closing the emulator and (I believe, not 100% sure) doing a full rebuild and deploy of your app will wipe out the isolated storage.  As long as you leave the emulator running and just do incremental builds, anything in isolated storage should be persisted.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong then because it doesn't persist even on my WP. I have however sorted this problem, you think you've searched everywhere and then suddenly! I can't post the answer until tomorrow though (as I'm a new user).

Comment: If the `varbinary(MAX)` type is supported in SqlCE, it should be used in preference to `image`.

Comment: @richard: varbinary(max) is not supported.  For longer data (i.e. > 8000 bytes) you must use an image type.